# Ignore Java.exe from Path and use the one from directory I am in

Tags: java, path, directory, jvm, noclassdeffounderror

I setup Java 6 to be used by all other application. Normal setup with JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, etc. This is working fine.

I have another application that needs Java 7. I downloaded Java 7.exe and extraced tools.zip from it to a folder. Now I am trying to check the version going to the `bin` folder. When I type in `java -version`, I get the following error.

```
error occurred during initialization of vm 
java/lang/noclassdeffounderror java/lang/object
```

where as `java -fullversion` shows Java 7. It looks like even though I am in the  bin folder where Java.exe exists, it still getting the one from PATH?!?!

How do I use the java.exe from a folder ignoring the one from PATH?

Comment: You need much more than `java` to run java.  You need all the `rt.jar` and `lib` which come with Java.  It sounds like you are missing some part of the JRE or it can't find your JRE.

Comment: I guess, you are right. Though I have all the files extracted properly, some jar files were left as ".pack". I had to convert them to .jar files. That seems to work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Please post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need much more than java to run java. You need all the rt.jar and lib which come with Java. It sounds like you are missing some part of the JRE or it can't find your JRE.

I suggest you re-install the version you need and run it using the full path name like

```
c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java" -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

By using the full path name you can use any specific version from any directory.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. When I unzipped the exe file, it did not unpack the .pack files. I ran a small batch script to recursively change the pack to jar files and it now it works!